# More Than One's Life's Worth - Meaning

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

> ... they'll be watching the Floo Network, and **it's more than our life's worth** to set up an unauthorized Portkey." ...

[From *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix* page 51] What does "more than our life's worth" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roughly, it means "not worth the danger".

The implication is that the risk in setting up an unauthorized Portkey is very great, and that someone who gets caught setting up an unauthorized Portkey will suffer greatly, so that the benefits of doing it are not worth the risk.

Comment: +1 and to be clear that "life's" is a contraction of "life is", rather than a possessive, so it means, "*more than our life **is worth***" rather than "*more than **the value of our life***"